# Fractional scaling or --scale on one monitor affects the other monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop and have an external monitor connected. They have different resolutions and dimensions. When I change the fractional scale of the external monitor (screen 2), the sizes of everything in screen 1 changes as well. Why does this happen?

I would like screen 1 to remain as it is and change only screen 2 (arima 27")

I have also tried running the --scale command and it affects both my screens as well.

```
xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP-1-1 2560/381x1440/214+0+0  eDP-1-1
 1: +HDMI-0 1920/600x1080/330+2560+0  HDMI-0

xrandr --output HDMI-0 --scale 1.2x1.2
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem of using scaling on Xorg, but you cannot switch to Wayland because you are using Nvidia drivers.

Try the solution mentioned here: https://www.lguruprasad.in/blog/2020/01/13/how-to-get-a-dual-monitor-setup-with-mixed-dpi-working-on-xorg/

The trick is to apply some sort of ‘upscale’ to the lower resolution monitor.

Comment: thank you i have read it and will try it out